# Submit form only if a function return true

Tags: javascript

I need a way to submit the form ONLY if foo return true. I tried this code but it submits the form even if foo return false.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return foo();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo() {
        // if... return true
        // else return false
    }
</script>
```

If I use the onsubmit function, then it submits first. So it's not good in my case.

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: no, any error in the console

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e4tdzme4/2/ - looks fine - can you try to recreate the issue in the fiddle

Comment: HTML5 form validation will do this automatially...?

Comment: I know, but it must work on old browsers too.

Comment: but a better solution will be is to use the form's submit event instead of the click event handler - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e4tdzme4/3/

Comment: Ops, I have removed "return" in the "onclick='return foo();'

Comment: @xRobot then it is a typo.. and probably you should delete the question... but consider using the `onsubmit` event handler instead of `onclick` as given above

Comment: possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008353/form-submit-if-function-return-true  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335440/how-to-make-form-only-submit-if-all-functions-return-true

Comment: with onsubmit, it submits first. So it doesn't seem good. Or no ?

Answer (score 2):

you can try alternative method using jquery ajax submit as follows, which I am using, may helpful to u too..

```
 var request;
    $("#YourFormId").submit(function(event){

  if(yourFunction()==false) {
         return false;
     }

        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }
       var $form = $(this);
       var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
       var serializedData = $form.serialize();
       $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
       request = $.ajax({
            url: "yourFormActionPage.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        }); 
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            //ok
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             //track it
        });

        request.always(function () {
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the form's submit event.  You can put the conditional in the submit event handler so the submission is halted when `foo()` does not return true.

(NOTE: I had to guess what the selector might be for your form since it's not part of your question)

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit(function(e) {
  if (!foo()) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax submit.

```
<form class="formbox" method="post" action="/your/action/url" id="myForm" name="myForm">
                    <input type="text" id="name" class="name" name="name" value=""/>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return foo();" />                      
              </form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function foo() {
    if(1==1) {
        alert("Success: Going to call the function");
        $("#myForm").submit(); //calling function.
    } else {
        alert("Error: ");
    }
}
```